# Import-through in Docker

Tags: python, docker, python-module

I've the main workbench folder (WORKDIR in Dockerfile) which contains the folder `initialize` with the file `max_init.py`. The problem is that when I run the image, it cant import that module:

```
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from initialize.max_init import *
ImportError: No module named initialize.max_init
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY . /workbench
WORKDIR /workbench
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8888
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

I think that the problem is my lack of experience in Docker, but I cant find a solution by myself

Edit: hierarchy:

```
workbench    
    |-- app.py
        |-- initialize
            |-- max_init.py
```

Comment: initialize is not a package. it misses the `__init__.py` file. Its not a Docker related problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to write an `__init__.py` file in your `initialize` module folder? Does it properly onboard your `max_init.py` file? If you aren't familiar with the convention, explainers abounds.

1. Official: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages
2. Flask explainer that I found personally quite easy to grasp: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/packages/

Edit: I see from updates that this is indeed the problem. You should be fine if you fix it...I don't even think you need to rebuild the docker image but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Thanks u, thats the problem, i forgot the __init__

Comment: Great! If the answer solved the problem for you, please mark it answered